# Jquery fade images and menu drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a problem with internet explorer 6 and 7, please look this example

http://www.aerocom.net.au/index.php?id=hosted-services

I lost the submenus when i pass over them just in ie7 and ie6 please i need you help.

Cheers

Comment: i resolved it thanks anyways.

#header {z-index:1;}

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you need to validate your page `16 Errors, 9 warning(s)`